# How to visualize domain and codomain mappings and turn to function notation

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm a little bit stuck in trying to wrap my head around this function

F:[X → [Y → Z]] to [(X × Y ) → Z]

I understand that the domain is a function whose domain is a function whose domain is X and codomain is a function whose domain is Y and codomain is Z, and the codomain of F is a function whose domain is all the ordered pairs in X x Y with codomain Z.

But how do I visualize that and write F as a function?

Answer (score 0):

F(x) is a function F(x):Y -> Z.
Thus the other side is a function G:X×Y -> Z
that maps (x,y) to F(x)(y) where of course F(x) is itself a map.
In short G(x,y) = F(x)(y).
Yes, it's a head twister.

Comment: is there a way to concisely write as one function? perhaps F(f(x)) = f(x)(y)?

Comment: See edit. @yasgur99